# Removing Keys in Synchronized LinkedHashMap from a Guava ListMultimap Copy

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, guava, multimap

I have a `forwardMap` that defines a one-to-one relationship and uses `ListMultimap` to store the inverted `forwardMap` that has a one-to-many relationship:

```
class Object1 { // with custom equals and hashCode }
class Object2 { // with custom equals and hashCode }

class ObjectManager {
  Map<Object1, Object2> forwardMap = 
    Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<>());
  ListMultimap<Object2, Object1> reverseMap = 
    Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimaps.forMap(forwardMap), LinkedListMultimap.create());
}
```

I'd like to implement `put` method in `ObjectManager` that

- puts an `Object1` into both Maps.
- removes existing `Object1` by insertion order from both Maps if there are too many `Object1` mapped to the same `Object2`.

```
@Synchronized
public void put(Object1 newForwardKey) {
  Optional<Object1> _closestForwardKey = 
    forwardMap.keySet().stream()
      .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(o -> calculateDistance(o, newForwardKey)));

  // assign matchedForwardValue to a new Object2 by default
  Object2 matchedForwardValue = new Object2();
  
  if (_closestForwardKey.isPresent()) {
    Object1 closestForwardKey = _closestForwardKey.get();
    // reset forwardValue only if closestForwardKey passes some other matching
    if (someOtherMatching(closestForwardKey, newForwardKey))
      matchedForwardValue = forwardMap.get(closestForwardKey);
  }

  // create appropriate entries for each map
  forwardMap.put(newForwardKey, matchedForwardValue);
  reverseMap.put(matchedForwardValue, newForwardKey);

  // remove excessive Object1
  // modification to the forwardKeysByValue List view is reflected in reverseMap
  List<Object1> forwardKeysByValue = reverseMap.get(forwardValue);
  while (forwardKeysByValue.size() > MAX_REVERSE_VALUE_COUNT)
    forwardMap.remove(forwardKeysByValue.remove(0));
}
```

I did not test it in a multithreaded environment. Running the method in a single thread seems to have the correct behavior.

Test code:

```
Object2 o21 = new Object2(1);
Object2 o22 = new Object2(2);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Object1 o11 = new Object1(i);
  Object1 o12 = new Object1(i+10);

  objectManagerInstance.put(o11); // assume always match o21
  objectManagerInstance.put(o12); // assume always match o22
}
```

Contents of both Maps:

```
// forwardMap
Object1(4) -> Object2(1)
...
Object1(9) -> Object2(1)
Object1(14) -> Object2(2)
...
Object1(19) -> Object2(2)

// reverseMap
Object2(1) -> [Object1(4) ... Object1(9)]
Object2(2) -> [Object1(14) ... Object2(19)]
```

I would appreciate your help explaining:

- Is there a thread-safe implementation that doesn't synchronize both `forwardMap` and `reverseMap` on object level? Or this kind of action needs to "stop the world"?

### Edit 2

- Refactored code.
- Self-answered how to make original code more memory efficient (original code generates a reverseMap each time `put` needs to remove some objects)

Comment: Does it have to be a separate operation? Can you do it when you insert a mapping into `forwardMap`?

Comment: And if I understand it right, you aren't updating `reverseMap` when you remove from the `forwardMap`.

Comment: @user7 Thanks for your comment. It is preferable that I do the removal at insertion. I'd also like to update the `reverseMap` at insertion. However, I don't know how to correctly implement such update.

Comment: How do inserts happen? How are you keeping both maps updated?

Comment: @user7 I have edited the post to include insertion. I'm not keeping the `reverseMap` updated and was only using it to remove `Object1` that satisfies the requirements.

Comment: @user7 I made another edit and self-answered my first question. Now the method will update both `forwardMap` and `reverseMap` on insertion, and removes excessive objects. Still, I'd appreciate your insight about whether it's possible to make the method thread-safe without locking both maps.

Comment: @c21at share the answer please if you managed to solve it